# Java Persistence with Hibernate - annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been reading the book 'Java Persistence with Hibernate' and downloaded the source code. I am able to run the 'helloworld-native' files with XML mapping, but cannot run the annotated version of those files. Could anyone tell me if they had difficulty with that section or could they point it out step by step please?

The section I cannot pass is 2.2.1 Using Hibernate Annotations

When running 'ant schemaexport' I receive the following error message:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The dialect was not set. Set the property hibernate dialect.
```

Which I shouldn't have to do in the XML file as the book does not say to do so. I do it anyway and get the following message....

```
UserSuppliedConnectionProvider:23 - No connection properties specified - the user must supply the JDBC connection
```

In HibernateUtil I have tried both...

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Hibernate.cfg

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
        PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   
        <!-- ... Many property settings ... -->     
    <!-- List of annotated classes-->
    <mapping class="hello.Message"/>    
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

/**
 * Startup Hibernate and provide access to the singleton SessionFactory
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static {
    try {       
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
       throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      // Alternatively, we could look up in JNDI here
      return sessionFactory;
  }

  public static void shutdown() {
      // Close caches and connection pools
      getSessionFactory().close();
  }
}
```

Message.java

```
package hello;
import javax.persistence.*;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MESSAGES")
    public class Message {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "MESSAGE_TEXT")
private String text;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "NEXT_MESSAGE_ID")
private Message nextMessage;

private Message() {}

public Message(String text) {
this.text = text;
}

public Long getId() {
return id;
}

private void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
this.text = text;
}

public Message getNextMessage() {
return nextMessage;
}

public void setNextMessage(Message nextMessage) {
this.nextMessage = nextMessage;
}
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package hello;

import org.hibernate.*;
import persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    // ############################################################################

    // First unit of work
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Message message = new Message("Hello World");
    session.save(message);

    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    // ############################################################################

    // Second unit of work
    Session secondSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction secondTransaction = secondSession.beginTransaction();

    List messages =
        secondSession.createQuery("from Message m order by m.text asc").list();

    System.out.println( messages.size() + " message(s) found:" );

    for ( Iterator iter = messages.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Message loadedMsg = (Message) iter.next();
        System.out.println( loadedMsg.getText() );
    }

    secondTransaction.commit();
    secondSession.close();

    // ############################################################################

    // Third unit of work
    Session thirdSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction thirdTransaction = thirdSession.beginTransaction();

    // message.getId() holds the identifier value of the first message
    Message loadedMessage = (Message) thirdSession.get( Message.class, message.getId());
    loadedMessage.setText( "Greetings Earthling" );
    loadedMessage.setNextMessage(
        new Message( "Take me to your leader (please)" )
    );

    thirdTransaction.commit();
    thirdSession.close();

    // ############################################################################

    // Final unit of work (just repeat the query)
    // TODO: You can move this query into the thirdSession before the commit, makes more sense!
    Session fourthSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction fourthTransaction = fourthSession.beginTransaction();

    messages =
        fourthSession.createQuery("from Message m order by m.text asc").list();

    System.out.println( messages.size() + " message(s) found:" );

    for ( Iterator iter = messages.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Message loadedMsg = (Message) iter.next();
        System.out.println( loadedMsg.getText() );
    }

    fourthTransaction.commit();
    fourthSession.close();


    // Shutting down the application
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: I am guessing that your config file hibernate.cfg.xml file cannot be found or is not configured correctly. Can you post the whole code - config file and java class ?

Comment: i have uploaded the code

Comment: Source code also available there http://www.manning.com/bauer2/